# Pandas returns empty filtered DataFrame only when I'm using Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have DataFrame that obtained with this code:

```
    file_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, 'movie_conversations.txt')
    movie_conversations = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=r"\+\+\+\$\+\+\+", encoding='cp1251', engine='python', names=['characterID_1', 'characterID_2', 'movieID', 'list_of_the_utterances'])
    movie_conversations.head()
```

it returns this frame, and it's okay:

```
|characterID_1|characterID_2|movieID|list_of_the_utterances           |
|-------------|-------------|-------|---------------------------------|
|u0           |u2           |m0     |['L194', 'L195', 'L196', 'L197'] |
|u0           |u2           |m0     |['L198', 'L199']                 |
|u0           |u2           |m0     |['L200', 'L201', 'L202', 'L203'] |
```

but when i'm try to filter like this, it returns empty DataFrame:

```
    movie_conversations[movie_conversations.movieID == "m0"]
```

furthermore, when i matched movieID column values like this:

```
    movie_conversations.movieID == "m0"
```

it returns False for all values in the column.

```
0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
4        False
         ...  
83092    False
83093    False
83094    False
83095    False
83096    False
Name: movieID, Length: 83097, dtype: bool
```

I have problem only with jupyterlab/notebook
When i'm run it in PyCharm/DataSpell - it's okay.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: may be whitespace. try: `movie_conversations.movieID.str.strip()`

Comment: Could you show the exact code you are running in jupyter and the code you are running in pycharm?

Comment: @Clegane right, it was a whitespace, thank you)

Comment: I recently changed the delimiter (removed spaces from it) and forgot about it. stupid mistake